# laravel 4 redirect from constructor This webpage has a redirect loop error

Tags: redirect, laravel-4, constructor

In my controller I have the following:

```
function __construct()
{
    Redirect::to('admin/login')->send();
}
```

However after it redirects the browser gives the following error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

The controller goes like this (omitted for brevity):

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    function __construct()
    {
        Redirect::to('admin/login')->send();
    }

    /**
     * Index view for admin
     *
     *@return view
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('admin.index');
    }

public function getLogin() 
    {
        return View::make('admin.login');
    }
```

And the routes file:

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
Route::controller('/{name?}', 'PagesController');
```

Comment: What's the controller in which you have that code? Can you show routes? Do you have any filter?

Comment: I just edited my answer with the controller and routes. The controller is a custom controler and I do not have any filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the entire constructor from that AdminController. If you put a redirect there, it will redirect every time you try to use a method inside it.

Just to make it work try:

```
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
```

instead of

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

And remove the constructor in AdminController. I can't imagine a situation in which I would redirect in a controller's constructor.

Comment: That's the whole point, it should redirect when accessing any method inside it if the user does not have proper credentials. The way it is now (automatically redirecting everyone) is just for testing purposes and getting redirect to actually work.

Comment: Ahh okay. And what controller and method handles the 'admin/login' route? Does it have any filter there?

Comment: It is a getLogin method also inside the Admin controller and no filters.

Comment: So that's the problem. The AdminController will redirect every request while that code is in the class construct. It doesn't matter if the user has permissions or not. So the error you get is because the user tries to go to getIndex in the AdminController, when the controller is created it finds the redirect code, which redirects to the same controller again: infinite loop

Comment: Where did you register the filter? Can you show that code?

Comment: I am not using filters. YES I see your point, if I try to redirect to a method in another controller it works. OMG I feel like a dumbass, though to my credit it was late last night :) I will modify my answer with this method and you update your answer so I can accept please.